# Access outer query value from inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to replace the one below with the following restrictions: no CTE and no UNION ALL.

I've researched this site for a similar problem and tried it myself using multiple variations of joining to sub select with no luck.

This is what I need to replace without using a CTE or UNION (ALL):

```
WITH TaskHierarchy(ParentTaskID, [TaskID], IsSummary)
AS
(
    SELECT t.ParentItemID, t.TaskItemID as [TaskID], t.IsSummary
    FROM dbo.TaskItem t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ParentItemID, t.TaskItemID as [TaskID], t.IsSummary
    FROM dbo.TaskItem t
    INNER JOIN TaskHierarchy th ON t.ParentItemID = th.TaskID
)
```

The columns returned and number of rows returned should match.

Comment: Why *can't* you use a (r)CTE? That's the "normal" solution for getting hierarchical data from a table.

Comment: I want to put this query into a materialized view which doesn't allow CTE or UNION

Comment: do you have sample data and output you can share with us? Maybe do up a http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ for us to play with.

Comment: Unfortunately my data security policy does not allow me to share the data.  I realize this makes it difficult to help me.

Comment: Well you could put it into a table that you truncate and rebuild :)

Comment: Any data shared should not be real data anyway. It should however be data that can demonstrate the real situation. In your example it looks like nothing more than a couple of integers and a bit, not sure how that could possibly give away any real information. But it doesn't really matter much. The data you want can't be done in a materialized view as it sits.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a #temp table?

Comment: How will that help with a `VIEW`, @level3looper? You can't perform DDL changes in a `VIEW`, and that includes temporary objects.

Comment: I suppose you *could* look at Jeff Moden's Hierarchies on Steroids articles, and build a huge hierarchy table... [#1: Convert an Adjacency List to Nested Sets](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/) & [#2: A Replacement for Nested Sets Calculations](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/94570/).

Comment: #temp-tables not supported

Comment: So far creating a table and and manually materializing it (truncate and rebuild) seems the only viable option.  So then the question becomes best way to trigger the update.  I have CDC turned on in AWS so i could watch for new files CDC creates in S3 bucket and then run a Lambda to rebuild the "materialized" table in sql database when a change notification occurs.  Or create update/insert/delete trigger on tables and have that call a function to truncate and rebuild the materialized table.  It must be updated near real time. 
Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried adding your CTE to a Table Valued Function and then basing your view off the TVF? I do this all the time when I have restrictions to functionality like UNION, etc...

Comment: Just tried table valued function approach.  TVF gets created ok.  However, trying to select from it in view with schema binding (materialized view) returns error saying table function is not schema bound.  A closer look at the microsoft docs does state you can't have:  Inline (TVF) or multi-statement table-valued functions (MSTVF)

Comment: Well, that just sucks. Would you be able to provide some sample data?